# Scheduler executor service hasn't stopped

Tags: android

```
scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //get date
        Date dateTime = new Date();
    }, 0, 30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //End of Scheduler
```

I've created this scheduler and it updated for every 30 seconds. Now I've created 2 options in menu to shutdown the scheduler. One in logout option and other option to shutdown the scheduler in next activity :

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case 1:

                // stop the scheduler
                scheduler.shutdown();

                // redirect to login page
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginPage.class);
                this.startActivity(intent);

                break;

            case 2:

                Intent i = new Intent(this, Location.class);
                this.startActivity(i);

                break;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
        return true;
    }
```

In Location class:

```
public void onToggleClicked(View view) {

        //assign Toggle button status
        boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

        if (on == true ) {

            //shutdown the scheduler
            scheduler.shutdown();
            }
```

The problem is scheduler hasn't shutdown in Location class . I want to stop the scheduler when button is unchecked and need to restart the scheduler again .Is that possible?

Comment: when the button is unchecked, on == false. Does the code `scheduler.shutdown();` in `Location` fire in debugger?

Answer (score 0):

`shutDown` doesn't allow to submit new tasks, but the queued tasks will be executed all the same. You could try with `shoutDownNow` which attempts to stop also all actively executing tasks. You can find the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown())

Comment: the documentation stays clearly that the ExecutorService attempts to stop, not that it stops the tasks